# Tradução de rotas com CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, route

Estou estudando CakePHP para possível utilização em um projeto, e o ponto crucial desse projeto é que ele seja multi-idioma. Só que eu já pesquisei muito sobre tradução das rotas:

```
  http://projeto.com/contact

  http://projeto.com.br/contato

  http://projeto.es/contacto
```

Mas não encontrei um conteúdo que aborde o tema. Alguém tem essa resposta? :)

Comment: Talvez http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427391/cakephp-2-x-i18n-route pode te ajudar

Comment: Mas assim vou ter que registrar rota por rota? Ou seja meu projeto tem mais ou menos umas 30 páginas e vou ter que adicionar ali as 30 rotas? Obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as páginas forem estáticas, você vai ter que criar uma por uma.
Para simplificar o processo você pode fazer o seguinte:

**Controller**

```
public function contact() {
    ...

    $this->render('contact');
    $this->response->send();
    $this->_stop();
}

public function contato() {
    $this->contact(); 
}

public function contacto() {
    $this->contact(); 
}
```

**Viewer**

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Contact'), array('action' => __('contact')));
```